# How to send back data to a server in a PWA website

Tags: json, server, web, progressive-web-apps, pull

I've searched and I can only find tutorials to pull info from a server to update the latest info of my PWA app using JSON. But I can't find any way and any example to fetch data back to a server to mantain for instance a Database updated and display that to all users which may use that PWA.

For example, I have a PWA that let me login (client-server communication), then it displays a list of contacts that were stored in a Database. I can delete, modify or add new users to this list from my PWA app, and after doing that, they'll update on my server Database, so if my friend Paul, wants to check the updated list from his account, he'll see the new changes.

How Can I do that? Which language would I have to use, php and Javascript (Ajax)? Which is the most fluid and optimized way to do it according to a Progressive Web App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to store user changes back to the server(webservice and then to the data base).

You have to make an AJAX call to your web service and pass the required data needed to store in DB.

Here is an example.
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

Depending on the framework you are using, you might have more options to call a web service. Like here is an example for Angular -> https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp